# Azure Chaos Studio with Chaos Mesh VNET Injection in Private Clusters Unsuccessful

Tags: linux, azure-aks, chaos, sre

We are beginning to evaluate Azure Chaos Studio usage with Chaos Mesh k8s experiments (AKS Chaos Mesh Pod Chaos for example).

Our clusters are private and we've enabled VNET injection when setting them as Chaos targets which creates 2 subnets in the given VNET. Chaos Studio uses these two new subnets to execute the experiments according to the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/chaos-studio/chaos-studio-tutorial-aks-portal

After configuring the experiment and giving it the correct role (Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role) as well as ensuring local accounts are enabled, when running the correctly configured experiment, it fails with no details about the failure.

I'm unable to find any logs or information as to why it is failing.

Chaos Mesh itself seems to be working fine, I'm able to use the dashboard to successfully run experiments on both clusters this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Experiment execution details in the "experiments" blade, you will see the specific details of the execution and how long it took to fail, as well as other information regarding logging which might shed more light on the cause of failure.